# Multiple dex files defined

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Ok I know there are many questions and answers on SO about this topic. I have read so many and the results are usually the same, you have conflicting dependencies. Some even suggested running gradlew dependencies to get a tree. Oddly enough this command shows all depencies are running the same version number. Any help is much appreciated, I'm at a loss. Below find my command output, error from AndroidStudio and app.gradle file. I should also mention that this error occurs only when trying to debug to a device, not when gradle builds and syncs.

**Error**

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

**app.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.company.company"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
}
```

**Command output**

```
:app:dependencies

------------------------------------------------------------
Project :app
------------------------------------------------------------

_debugAndroidTestApk - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
No dependencies

_debugAndroidTestCompile - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
No dependencies

_debugApk - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1
|         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.1
\--- com.android.support:design:23.0.1
     +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1 (*)
     \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1 (*)

_debugCompile - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1
|         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.1
\--- com.android.support:design:23.0.1
     +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1 (*)
     \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1 (*)

_debugUnitTestApk - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
No dependencies

_debugUnitTestCompile - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
No dependencies

_releaseApk - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1
|         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.1
\--- com.android.support:design:23.0.1
     +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1 (*)
     \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1 (*)

_releaseCompile - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1
|         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.1
\--- com.android.support:design:23.0.1
     +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1 (*)
     \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1 (*)

_releaseUnitTestApk - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
No dependencies

_releaseUnitTestCompile - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
No dependencies

androidJacocoAgent - The Jacoco agent to use to get coverage data.
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.4.201502262128/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.4.201502262128.pom
\--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.agent:0.7.4.201502262128

androidJacocoAnt - The Jacoco ant tasks to use to get execute Gradle tasks.
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.ant/0.7.4.201502262128/org.jacoco.ant-0.7.4.201502262128.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.report/0.7.4.201502262128/org.jacoco.report-0.7.4.201502262128.pom
\--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.ant:0.7.4.201502262128
     +--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:0.7.4.201502262128
     |    \--- org.ow2.asm:asm-debug-all:5.0.1
     +--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.report:0.7.4.201502262128
     |    +--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:0.7.4.201502262128 (*)
     |    \--- org.ow2.asm:asm-debug-all:5.0.1
     \--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.agent:0.7.4.201502262128

androidTestApk - Classpath packaged with the compiled 'androidTest' classes.
No dependencies

androidTestCompile - Classpath for compiling the androidTest sources.
No dependencies

androidTestProvided - Classpath for only compiling the androidTest sources.
No dependencies

androidTestWearApp - Link to a wear app to embed for object 'androidTest'.
No dependencies

apk - Classpath packaged with the compiled 'main' classes.
No dependencies

archives - Configuration for archive artifacts.
No dependencies

compile - Classpath for compiling the main sources.
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1
|         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.1
\--- com.android.support:design:23.0.1
     +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1 (*)
     \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1 (*)

debugApk - Classpath packaged with the compiled 'debug' classes.
No dependencies

debugCompile - Classpath for compiling the debug sources.
No dependencies

debugProvided - Classpath for only compiling the debug sources.
No dependencies

debugWearApp - Link to a wear app to embed for object 'debug'.
No dependencies

default - Configuration for default artifacts.
No dependencies

default-mapping - Configuration for default mapping artifacts.
No dependencies

default-metadata - Metadata for the produced APKs.
No dependencies

provided - Classpath for only compiling the main sources.
No dependencies

releaseApk - Classpath packaged with the compiled 'release' classes.
No dependencies

releaseCompile - Classpath for compiling the release sources.
No dependencies

releaseProvided - Classpath for only compiling the release sources.
No dependencies

releaseWearApp - Link to a wear app to embed for object 'release'.
No dependencies

testApk - Classpath packaged with the compiled 'test' classes.
No dependencies

testCompile - Classpath for compiling the test sources.
No dependencies

testDebugApk - Classpath packaged with the compiled 'testDebug' classes.
No dependencies

testDebugCompile - Classpath for compiling the testDebug sources.
No dependencies

testDebugProvided - Classpath for only compiling the testDebug sources.
No dependencies

testDebugWearApp - Link to a wear app to embed for object 'testDebug'.
No dependencies

testProvided - Classpath for only compiling the test sources.
No dependencies

testReleaseApk - Classpath packaged with the compiled 'testRelease' classes.
No dependencies

testReleaseCompile - Classpath for compiling the testRelease sources.
No dependencies

testReleaseProvided - Classpath for only compiling the testRelease sources.
No dependencies

testReleaseWearApp - Link to a wear app to embed for object 'testRelease'.
No dependencies

testWearApp - Link to a wear app to embed for object 'test'.
No dependencies

wearApp - Link to a wear app to embed for object 'main'.
No dependencies
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `design` library contains the `appcompat-v7` lib and you specify it explicitly

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
}
```

You should be good if you just exclude the `support` libs group from the classpath of the `design` lib.  You could do something like this

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile('com.android.support:design:23.0.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
}
```

You can see this in the dependency graph here:

```
compile - Classpath for compiling the main sources.
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1
|         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.1
\--- com.android.support:design:23.0.1
     +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1 (*)  <-- already in project class path
     \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1 (*) <-- already in project class path
```

You mention that this only happens during debug.  I'm guessing that is because your proguard is removing the offending classes for your `release` builds but not `debug`.  You may also want to try updating your `build.gradle` to run proguard over both `debug` and `release` builds

```
android {
    // other stuff...
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    // other stuff...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I implemented both of these code changes but I am still left with the same problem. Is there any chance its the version of gradle I'm using? (1.4.0-beta6)

Comment: Follow up: Combining both of your suggestions and upgrading to 1.5.0-beta1 fixed the problem.

Comment: Using compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1' and
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1' doesn't generate the issue.